# Server load avg. hitting 16-20, but all resources under 90% usage?

Tags: linux, debian, performance, performance-tuning, load-average

As you can see in the image shared below, the server load peaked to almost 20 but the CPU, RAM, DISK IO and Network I/O remained well under their full capacity. My question is:

1). What caused the load?
2). Is it ok and normal to ignore these types of high-load spikes?

[image: Load average]

Comment: You could try sorting your processes by CPU usage.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have 8 cores a load of 16-20 translates to 2-2.5 single-processor style, which is not bad (basically, two cars at the stop light instead of one).  You have a process ... ffmpeg maybe? ... that seems to be hogging a single core (not multi-thread happy I'd guess) and probably doing a lot of I/O (corresponding bump in lower left chart)

I would not worry about this, except to wonder why user www-data is able to kick off CPU intensive processes, or if it's causing slowdowns elsewhere.

Comment: You can see a bigger image at http://i.stack.imgur.com/rNi2i.png , nginx is running under `www-data` user and is launching `ffmpeg` - is this not recommended?

Comment: I can't say, I don't know what your application is or who it's exposed to.  I certainly wouldn't want the general public to be able to drive my electric bill up with transcodes unless I understood everything.